# Uploading file using local upload? Only

Tags: testrigor

How to upload file from local drive only instead of creating the "Test Data" and uploading to the testrigor

Since some of my files are Patented and i do not want to upload them in "Testrigor" but will it be able to take from my local drive?

drag file from "/Users/name/Desktop/Objects/Assets/Uplaoded/Secure/Secure_v/Secure_vv/object.png" into "Select or drag & drop files to upload"

Answer (score 0):

testRigor cannot load a file from your local drive. The file must be web accessible by a link.

The more convenient way in testRigor is to upload the file into testRigor's test data section. Then upload within the test case and
if there is a button to click and open the file system on our PC. You can use this try with this command:

enter stored value "file-URL-name" into input type file

If not, then you could use a file URL as long as the file has no restrictions.

Here's an example:

drag file "https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/10/file_example_JPG_100kB.jpg" onto "file"